# Check Expired Token (after a visit)

Tags: .net, token

I'm implementing a model which I'll have to reupdate the users, so I want to deliver a unique link to the users and after confirmed the update, I expire that link, so I prevent reusing that link.

How do I generate a random secure token for that?

The performance of checking if the token was already visited isn't a problem, it will not affect a huge number of users.

Comment: *"The performance of checking if the token was already visited isn't problem, it will not affect a huge number of users."* - which assumes that no one tries to DoS you with URLs which you need to verify and where each takes a long time to verify. See for example [Long Passwords Lead to DOS Attacks, Django Developers Warn](https://news.softpedia.com/news/Long-Passwords-Lead-to-DOS-Attacks-Django-Developers-Warn-383684.shtml) about this type of attack.

Comment: *" ... after confirmed the update, I expire that link, so I prevent to reuse that link"* - actually, this is not expiring (time based) but deactivating the token based on some action (i.e. token used). This can simply be done by creating a random token and putting it into a database as valid for this specific action. Once used simply delete it from the database. Implementation of this is trivial but depends on your specific server side capabilities (programming languages and database available) and a specific implementation would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this pattern for unique one-time links:

API endpoint:

```
/activation/<one-time token>
```

`<one-time token>` is a path param which you look up in the db. I would generate these tokens as 128-bit random numbers to prevent the DoS attack Steffen describes where bad guys guess the URLs and hit them before the legitimate user does. Generate them from your programming language's 'cryptographic' or 'secure' random number generator as an array of 16 random bytes, then convert that to hex (which will be 32 hex characters).

That means your users will have links like

```
/activation/79b2de3e62bf21e081b34d679f45c4a6
```

I have also seen this done with GUIDs, in which case you get links like the following (make sure you're using type 4 random GUIDs, since other types of GUID are based on MAC address, clock, etc and while they are unique, they are also fairly easy for bad guys to guess).

```
/activation/ab4762dc-2271-4f53-844c-db279983d6e8
```

You get the "one-time" property by deleting the token from the db as it is processed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update something in the user database, otherwise the whole operation makes no sense.

So, it makes sense to use a token that encodes that information. This way, the token automatically expires itself.

For example let us say that I want those users that have no valid birth date archived to update their birth date (or credit card expiration or whatever). I can set the birth date field to NULL or to a special date such as 0000-00-00 00:00:00, or to the existing, invalid, date (I have some way of determining it's invalid; it's the same way I determined which uses to send the token to).

Then I can generate a token from the user, the birth date, and a secret:

```
token := user.userId+':'+Crypto.SHA512(user.UserId + user.BirthDate.toLocaleDate() + 'S33kr1t')
```

So my token would be `31337:10952b847b3c5be46bdbb9c67b2f050f92f59f87cd1af5baf459012593d4ff1639c38a60c2010ee9adeb727d4025897ad9fb25a4d4f46ab8f22f0a64e13f8c94` (okay, maybe SHA-512 is a bit of an overkill).

Users send me the token and I authenticate them for the purpose of updating the information (I might require *also* to enter their password just to be sure). I can first verify that the token is still valid by retrieving the user info and re-calculating the token. If the supplied token and the regenerated one are the same, the token is valid.

When they update the information, the token is automatically invalidated because it will now be generated from different data.

You can also introduce a time factor by adding the timestamp in the token and in the hash:

```
31337:202103041715:f3dafa6e87a23baf56ed7e6bc...
```

Now you can first determine if the token is "too old" (reject immediately with a very low cost, no database check required).